# Avoid forced delay of setTimeout when breaking up long running JavaScript tasks

Tags: javascript, performance, internet-explorer, settimeout

I have a long running task in JavaScript, which I break up in chunks with a series of nested `setTimeout(processChunk, 0)`, similar to what is described [here](http://www.julienlecomte.net/blog/2007/10/28/). However, for each invocation, `setTimeout` adds an additional delay of 4 ms or more. This behaviour is [well known](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout#Nested_timeouts_forced_to_>4ms) and varies across browsers.

When I attempt to keep the processing time of each chunk at 50 ms or less, these additional delays increase total processing time by at least 10%.

*My question is*: Can I avoid the additional delay (and thus improve the processing speed) while maintaining backwards compatibility with ES3 browsers and old IE browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a straightforward workaround for this issue. Since the minimum delay of `setTimeout` is measured from when the timer is set, make sure to set timers at least 10–15 ms before each chunk should be processed. When several `setTimeout` are set, they queue up and the next one is invoked immediately after the previous, without the additional delay. This can be done with only 2 active timers:

```
function runLongTask() {
  var complete = false;
  function processChunk() {
    if(!complete) {
      /* ... process chunk, set complete flag after last chunk ... */
      //set new timer
      setTimeout(processChunk);
    } else {
      /* ... code to run on completion ... */
    }
  }
  //set a timer to start processing
  setTimeout(processChunk);
  //set an extra timer to make sure 
  //there are always 2 active timers,
  //this removes the extra delay provided
  //that processing each chunk takes longer
  //than the forced delay
  setTimeout(processChunk);
}
```

Below is a working demo comparing the workaround approach to the traditional approach of setting a new `setTimeout` after each chunk is processed. In the workaround there is always an extra `setTimeout` set ahead, reducing the processing time with about 4 ms or more for each chunk (about 40 ms or more for 10 chunks, as demonstrated below), provided that each chunk takes at least 4 ms to process. Note that the workaround demonstrates the use of only 2 active timers.

```js
function runForAtLeast15ms() {
  var d = (+new Date) + 15;
  while(+new Date < d);
}

function testTimeout(repetitions, next, workaround) {
  var startTime = +new Date;

  function runner() {
    if(repetitions > 0) {
      //process chunk
      runForAtLeast15ms();
      //set new timer
      setTimeout(runner);
    } else if(repetitions === 0) {
      //report result to console
      console.log((workaround? 'Workaround' : 'Traditional') + 
                  ' approach: ' +
                  ((+new Date) - startTime) + ' ms');
      //invoke next() function if provided
      next && next();
    }
    repetitions--;
  }

  setTimeout(runner);

  if(workaround){
   //make sure that there are always 2
   //timers running by setting an extra timer
   //at start
   setTimeout(runner);
  }
}

//First: repeat runForAtLeast15ms 10 times
//with repeated setTimeout
testTimeout(10, function(){
  //Then: repeat runForAtLeast15ms 10 times
  //using a repeated set of 2 setTimeout
  testTimeout(10, false, true);
});
```

Comment: You answered your own question at the same time you asked the question.

Comment: @Everald, That's right. [It is encouraged by SO](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/). I struggled with this question on my own recently and found a solution I would like to document and share. By sharing, someone may even provide a better solution.